# How can I use props image in React-Bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-props

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlmzE.png)
I want to use props but pictures don't come but other things come so how can I use props in React-Bootstrap (sorry for my English)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFrle.png)

Comment: can you also share from where and in which format you are sending the props to this component ?

Comment: First of all, the proper way to get help is to post code into stackoverflow and not to post images. If you post code into your text, press Ctrl K to on the lines that you post in order to designate it as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is saying that the image that you're getting has a security policy on it that only allows code that is running on the same server to access it. Pick an image that doesn't have that policy or if it's your image, change the [security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) on that image.

To check this, choose a different image from a different server.